# 64-bit image color declaring (16 bit per channel)

Tags: c#, image, colors

In C# I can declare new `48bitRGB` or `64bitRGBA` without problem, and in fact the right format is saved on disk.

However, when it comes to declaring a color, I am not able to declare color of more than 8-bit values. That seems to be because `Color` declarations expect no more than 8 bits per component.

The code I have so far:

```
int x;
int y;
int w = 512, h = 512;

Bitmap image = new Bitmap(w, h, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb); //New image with 16bit per channel, no problem

// Double 'for' control structure to go pixel by pixel on the whole image
for (y = 0; y < h; y++)
{
    for (x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        comp = somevalue; //Numeric component value
        // Lo que vaya por aqui
        System.Drawing.Color newColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, comp, comp, comp); // <= Here is the problem, values can't exceed 256 levels
        image.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
    }
}

image.Save(@"C:\test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); //Saving image to disk
```

What is a method for declaring a 16-bit color component in C#?

Comment: you could access the raw pixels, see here how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768711/setpixel-is-too-slow-is-there-a-faster-way-to-draw-to-bitmap

Comment: System.Drawing.Color internally uses a long (signed 64 bit integer) to represent it's RGBA value but all of it's operations accept ints, you'll need to create your own Bitmap class or use an equivalent graphics format library.

Comment: Yes, I am using WPF, why?

Answer (score 3):

The problem stems from the fact that the Bitmap class encapsulates a GDI+ bimap.

> GDI+ version 1.0 and 1.1 can read 16-bits-per-channel images, but such images are converted to an 8-bits-per-channel format for processing, displaying, and saving. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

So when you are setting the value of the pixels you are dealing with the 8 bit per channel format.

If use use unsafe code you can access the values directly, see [Get 64bpp image color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778227/get-64bpp-image-color).

Comment: I was trying to avoid direct access, but it seems there is no better way. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can avoid unsafe code by copying the entire backing array (or parts of it, depending on your operation) out of the image, and back in after processing, using `Marshal.Copy`.